# The url_for method cannot find the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have to make edit/create forms for several tables on one page (settings). Therefore I have created SettingsController.

Routes:

```
resources :settings, :only => :index do
  member do
    get 'cs_edit'
    put 'cs_update'
    post 'cs_create'
    delete 'cs_destroy'
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate
...
def cs_create
  @cs = CaseStatus.find(params[:id])
  @cs.save

  redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Case Status was created successfully'
end
```

The view part:

```
<%= form_for(@cs, :url => url_for(:action => 'cs_create', :controller => 'settings'), :class => 'status_form') do |cs_f| %>
```

The question is that I am getting the following error:

```
Showing /home/michael/public_html/development/fbtracker/app/views/settings/index.html.erb where line #98 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"cs_create", :controller=>"settings"}
Extracted source (around line #98):

95:                   <% end %>
96:                 </table>
97: 
98:                 <%= form_for(@cs, :url => url_for(:action => 'cs_create', :controller => 'settings'), :class => 'status_form') do |cs_f| %>
99:                   <%= cs_f.text_field :name, :class => 'sname' %>
100:                  <%= cs_f.text_field :owt, :class => 'owt' %>
101:                  <%= cs_f.submit 'Add' %>
```

Also I just have checked routes:

```
$ rake routes
...
cs_edit_setting GET    /settings/:id/cs_edit(.:format)             {:action=>"cs_edit", :controller=>"settings"}
cs_update_setting PUT    /settings/:id/cs_update(.:format)           {:action=>"cs_update", :controller=>"settings"}
cs_create_setting POST   /settings/:id/cs_create(.:format)           {:action=>"cs_create", :controller=>"settings"}
cs_destroy_setting DELETE /settings/:id/cs_destroy(.:format)          {:action=>"cs_destroy", :controller=>"settings"}
settings GET    /settings(.:format)                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"settings"}
```

As you can see, the route matches {:action=>"cs_create", :controller=>"settings"} is exist. But url_for cannot find this route. Why?

Comment: I believe there is a more elegant (rails's) way to construct form_for without using `url_for` method.

Comment: And how? :)
Sorry, I am newbie in rails.

Comment: `form_for( @cs, cs_create_setting_path, :class => 'status_form' )`

Comment: @Bohdan Did you want to say that I should to use Nested resources? i.e.:
`resources :settings { resources :case_statuses }`

Comment: Why are you not using the default routing and controller names for Settings controller? Are there two separate models? `Setting` and `CaseStatus`?

Comment: yes, create is method of the collection not member

Comment: also you have to specify that form uses `POST` not `GET`

Comment: Michael, don't have to say sorry for being a newbie. We all are, all of the time, at something... PS: RailsCasts and RailsGuides are your friends. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html also http://asciicasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough

Comment: @user482594 I haven't Settings model. I have CaseStatus, ProjectStatus, Priority, Type and many other simple models. And I think it will be better if user can edit all these models at one page - settings.

Comment: @tardate, many thanks :-) Will learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined cs_create as a member method, but your url_for call doesn't give it an object. If you really want to use `url_for` this way, you can do this:

```
url_for(:id => @cs.id, :action => 'cs_create', :controller => 'settings')
```

Or alternatively make it a collection method:

```
resources :settings, :only => :index do
  post 'cs_create', :on => :collection
  member do
    get 'cs_edit'
    put 'cs_update'
    delete 'cs_destroy'
  end
end
```

**However**, as mentioned in the comments, this is basically ignoring all of the support that rails provides to make this easy. I'd recommend:

- define a resources routing for CaseStatus that can use all the standard RESTful routes (that doesn't mean you can't make all these settings visible on a single page under /settings
- use standard url helpers instead of url_for
- understand that you don't need a separate path for all the HTTP actions (e.g. show, update and delete are usually share all the same path, but with different HTTP actions)

Comment: Yeah. I strongly agree with this response. Rails way!